# Psycopg2 issue inserting values into an existing table in the database

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am having a hard time understanding why psycopg2 has a problem with the word 'user'. I am trying to insert values into a table called user with the columns user_id, name, password. I am getting a programmingError: syntax error at or near "user". open_cursor() is a function used to open a cursor for database operations.

Here is my code:

```
query = """INSERT INTO user (name, password) VALUES (%s, %s);"""
data = ('psycouser', 'sha1$ba316b$52dd71da1e331247f0a7ab869e1b072210add9c1')
with open_cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(query, data)
    print "Done."
```

Comment: Please always quote table names.

Answer (score 4):

because user is a part of sql language.

try taking it in dbl quotes:

```
query = 'INSERT INTO "user" (name, password) VALUES (%s, %s);'
```